# My app doesn't see buttons via "case R.id.x"

Tags: android

I'm total beginner in Android programmimg. I have MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml files in my app. In xml I have few buttons declared like that:

```
            android:id="@+id/tablicowy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickHandler"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_tablicowy"
```

ofc inside "Button" (I simple don't know how to write it here as "<" make word "Button" invisible on this site :) )
In .java file I have switch with cases like that:

```
public void onClickHandler(View widok) {
switch (widok.getId()) {

case R.id.tablicowy:
noweOkno(PoziomyActivity.class);
break;
```

but Eclipse compiler doesn't see "tablicowy" as an ID and says "tablicowy cannot be resolved or is not a field. I cannot figure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Please build the project after declaring new id

Comment: Don't use Eclipse anymore. Its deprecated. This sort of things happens on that IDE and are fixed on Android Studio. To fix this you now need to clean the project

Answer (score 0):

Check the project->build automatically is checked, if it is select project->clean and do a clean on all projects, don't worry its not deleting anything its just sort of rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

It showed that you may have some error in your Layout file,just correct it !
Moreover,you can clean your project to rebuild your R.java file .